# Regexp with mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I spend about one hour, and read many tutorial ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), Blogs.),

still can't finger it out, and this is what I want to get:

```
http://localhost/post/create
http://localhost/post/create/
http://localhost/post/create/?ID=123
```

the real path is:

```
http://localhost/includes/function/post/create.php
```

so I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)(/.*)?$ includes/function/post/$1.php$2
```

It looks fine but **it won't work if the URL is end with '/' or '/?ID=123'**,

and sometimes it just get more worse just throw me an HTTP 500 error,

any solution please?

**edit:** I hope that I can use the above three ways with only one rule, is it possible?

**edit2:** I realize that I just need to remove `-MultiView` in my .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/?$ /includes/function/post/$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Sorry, it's still not work, I hope I can use the above three ways with only one rule.

Comment: It worked fine now, I realize that I just need to remove `-MultiViews`